# MSSQL Single Listener for Multiple AGs

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I was looking for a solution in which my application, one which I can configure only one Listener param, if we can address multiple Availability Groups or not.
I have heard of using multiple listeners for one or multiple AGs, but is it possible to use a single listener and address multiple AGs?

Comment: see the [FAQ](http://sqlha.com/2012/04/13/allans-alwayson-availability-groups-faq/) from Allan Hirt.

Comment: Just to clarify - when you say multiple AGs, are you simply meaning multiple servers in an AG, or are you literally meaning something like AG1 (Primary and 3 secondaries), AG2 (Primary and secondary), and AG3 (Primary, live secondary, 2 read-only secondaries)?

Answer (score 3):

> but is it possible to use a single listener and address multiple AGs.

A listener is specific to Instance of AG so you cannot connect to multiple AG's using one listener. If you have multiple instances you have to use multiple AG's.

How do you think a single listener will manager multiple AG's now how will it know which AG to connect ?